# Split the title of a table into more than one row

Tags: tables, spacing

Suppose I had the following;

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Table1}  \\ \hline
A very long equation with k as input & Answer \\ \hline
1 & -19.0123  \\ \hline
2 & -16.4377 \\ \hline
3 & -13.3349 \\ \hline
4 & -11.7427  \\ \hline
5 & -10.1329 \\ \hline
6  & -9.0075 \\ \hline
7 & -6.0001 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{table2}  \\ \hline
A very long equation with k as input & Answer \\ \hline
1 & -16.0123  \\ \hline
2 & -12.4377 \\ \hline
3 & -9.5532 \\ \hline
4 & -5.7427  \\ \hline
5 & -4.1329 \\ \hline
6  & -3.0075 \\ \hline
7 & -3.0001 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{table3}  \\ \hline
A very long equation with k as input & Answer \\ \hline
1 & -5.0123  \\ \hline
2 & -2.4377 \\ \hline
3 & -3.3349 \\ \hline
4 & -1.7427  \\ \hline
5 & -1.1329 \\ \hline
6  & -1.0075 \\ \hline
7 & -1.0001 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Notice how the first columns only have small entries (At most they will have 8 figures), I was wondering what I could insert in this to make it so that that the title of column 1 (the long equation with k as input) would split into more than one row - whilst remaining centred.

Thanks - and apologies if this has already been answered, 
Rob.

EDIT: The end idea is to ensure all tables are next to one another on the same row.

Comment: Please read the documentation of the booktabs package: http://ctan.sciserv.eu/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load `array` package and declare a new column type

```
\newcolumntype{C}{@{}>{\Centering\arraybackslash}m{0.14\linewidth}}
```

with suitable value for 0.14 in `0.14\linewidth`. I have used `\Centering`  command from `ragged2e` package inside the column. Also you will need `[t]` for `tabular` as in

```
 \begin{tabular}[t]{|C|c|}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}m{0.14\linewidth}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{|C|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Table1}  \\ \hline
A very long equation with k as input & Answer \\ \hline
1 & -19.0123  \\ \hline
2 & -16.4377 \\ \hline
3 & -13.3349 \\ \hline
4 & -11.7427  \\ \hline
5 & -10.1329 \\ \hline
6  & -9.0075 \\ \hline
7 & -6.0001 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{|C|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{table2}  \\ \hline
A very long equation with k as input & Answer \\ \hline
1 & -16.0123  \\ \hline
2 & -12.4377 \\ \hline
3 & -9.5532 \\ \hline
4 & -5.7427  \\ \hline
5 & -4.1329 \\ \hline
6  & -3.0075 \\ \hline
7 & -3.0001 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%\quad
\begin{tabular}[t]{|C|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{table3}  \\ \hline
$a+b+f+c+d+g+t+r+e+y+u+h+g+b+u+y+u+r+t+y=Z$ & Answer \\ \hline
1 & -5.0123  \\ \hline
2 & -2.4377 \\ \hline
3 & -3.3349 \\ \hline
4 & -1.7427  \\ \hline
5 & -1.1329 \\ \hline
6  & -1.0075 \\ \hline
7 & -1.0001 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Following the tradition of the site, vertical lines are evil and a table that uses `booktabs` is neat, here is a `booktabs` version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}m{0.17\linewidth}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{CcCcCc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Table1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{table2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{table3}  \\ \midrule
A very long equation with k as input & Answer & A very long equation with k as input & Answer & A very long equation with k as input & Answer  \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
1 & -19.0123 &  1 & -16.0123 & 1 & -5.0123  \\
2 & -16.4377 &  2 & -12.4377 & 2 & -2.4377 \\
3 & -13.3349 &  3 & -9.5532  & 3 & -3.3349 \\
4 & -11.7427 &  4 & -5.7427  & 4 & -1.7427  \\
5 & -10.1329 &  5 & -4.1329  & 5 & -1.1329 \\
6 & -9.0075  &  6 & -3.0075  & 6 & -1.0075 \\
7 & -6.0001  &  7 & -3.0001  & 7 & -1.0001 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the above tables, the number should have been in math mode (see the minus sign). To do that you can define another new column like

```
\newcolumntype{P}{>{$}c<{$}}
```

and use it as

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{CPCPCP}
```

Or.... use `siunitx` and its `S` column type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,ragged2e,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}m{0.17\linewidth}}
\newcolumntype{P}{S[table-format=3.4]}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{CPCPCP}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Table1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{table2} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{table3}  \\ \midrule
A very long equation with k as input & \mc{Answer} & A very long equation with k as input & \mc{Answer} & A very long equation with k as input & \mc{Answer}  \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
1 & -19.0123 &  1 & -16.0123 & 1 & -5.0123  \\
2 & -16.4377 &  2 & -12.4377 & 2 & -2.4377 \\
3 & -13.3349 &  3 & -9.5532  & 3 & -3.3349 \\
4 & -11.7427 &  4 & -5.7427  & 4 & -1.7427  \\
5 & -10.1329 &  5 & -4.1329  & 5 & -1.1329 \\
6 & -9.0075  &  6 & -3.0075  & 6 & -1.0075 \\
7 & -6.0001  &  7 & -3.0001  & 7 & -1.0001 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @mrhappysmile I have added some more which may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using booktabs and ommit vertical lines, if you want to separate the tables, you could use `subtable` environments of `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[width=0.9\linewidth,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Three equations evaluated at $k$}
  \begin{subtable}{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Complicated function of $k$}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
      \toprule
      $k$ & Result \\
      \midrule
      1 & -19.0123  \\
      2 & -16.4377 \\
      3 & -13.3349 \\
      4 & -11.7427  \\
      5 & -10.1329 \\
      6  & -9.0075 \\ 
      7 & -6.0001 \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}%  
  \begin{subtable}{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Complicated function of $k$}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
      \toprule
      $k$ & Result \\
      \midrule
      1 & -19.0123  \\
      2 & -16.4377 \\
      3 & -13.3349 \\
      4 & -11.7427  \\
      5 & -10.1329 \\
      6  & -9.0075 \\ 
      7 & -6.0001 \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}%  
  \begin{subtable}{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Complicated function of $k$}
    \begin{tabular}{c c}
      \toprule
      $k$ & Result \\
      \midrule
      1 & -19.0123  \\
      2 & -16.4377 \\
      3 & -13.3349 \\
      4 & -11.7427  \\
      5 & -10.1329 \\
      6  & -9.0075 \\ 
      7 & -6.0001 \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}%  
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I think you should also consider tou round the values, are 4 digits meaningfull and necessary? And You could use the `S` columntype of siunitx to get the numbers properly aligned at the decimal point (Note the Braces around the titles):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[width=0.9\linewidth,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Three equations evaluated at $k$}
  \begin{subtable}{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Complicated function of $k$}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.0] S[table-format=-2.4]}
      \toprule
      {$k$} & {Result} \\
      \midrule
      1 & -19.0123  \\
      2 & -16.4377 \\
      3 & -13.3349 \\
      4 & -11.7427  \\
      5 & -10.1329 \\
      6  & -9.0075 \\ 
      7 & -6.0001 \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}%  
  \begin{subtable}{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Complicated function of $k$}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.0] S[table-format=-2.4]}
      \toprule
      {$k$} & {Result} \\
      \midrule
      1 & -19.0123  \\
      2 & -16.4377 \\
      3 & -13.3349 \\
      4 & -11.7427  \\
      5 & -10.1329 \\
      6  & -9.0075 \\ 
      7 & -6.0001 \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}%  
  \begin{subtable}{0.33\textwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Complicated function of $k$}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.0] S[table-format=-2.4]}
      \toprule
      {$k$} & {Result} \\
      \midrule
      1 & -19.0123  \\
      2 & -16.4377 \\
      3 & -13.3349 \\
      4 & -11.7427  \\
      5 & -10.1329 \\
      6  & -9.0075 \\ 
      7 & -6.0001 \\ 
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}%  
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: outout II]

You should also note that siunitx uses the correct minus sign, not a hyphen, and uses the monospaced figures.